# How to connect a node to a d3 tree after dragging it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am having a d3 tree that I rendered. The requirement is I can drag a node to another location so the user can expand that section separately.

I am able to add the drag code, but after the drag is complete the link between the parent and child is gone.

Do let me know how I can get this working. I am attaching an image of how it is looking with the code rendered.

[image]

```
var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
    w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
    i = 0,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([h, w]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

d3.json("d3/flare.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  root.x0 = h / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      toggle(d);
    }
  }

  // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
  root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  update(root);

});

function update(source) {

  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;    

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
       .call( drag);

  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -30 : 30; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();


  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) {

        if(d.target.weight == undefined) {
            return "1px";
        }
        else {
            return (d.target.weight % 5 * 5) + "px";
        }

      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return "#CD1";
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", function( d, i) {

    var selection = d3.selectAll( '.selected');

    if( selection[0].indexOf( this)==-1) {
        selection.classed( "selected", false);
        selection = d3.select( this);
        selection.classed( "selected", true);
    } 

    selection.attr("transform", function( d, i) {

        var coordinates = [0, 0];
        coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        var x = coordinates[0];
        var y = coordinates[1];

        return "translate(" + [ x, y ] + ")"
    })

    // reappend dragged element as last 
    // so that its stays on top 
    this.parentNode.appendChild( this);
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    // Update the links…
    var link = vis.selectAll("path.link");

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.style("stroke-width", function(d) {
            return "20px"
          })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return "#CD1";
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    update(root);

  });

// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact updating the links in the drag function, but they are using the `.x` and `.y` data attributes to determine the position. When you are updating the node's position, you're only setting the translation and not updating the data. To fix, update the data as well:

```
selection.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
    d.x = coordinates[0];
    d.y = coordinates[1];

    return "translate(" + [ d.x, d.y ] + ")"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried it and it don't seem to add the link. I have put the code in fsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mindgardener/S4dyL/ . Hope you can take  look if I am missing anything. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, so this is because you've been calling `update` to overwrite the data that you've set. I've updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S4dyL/1/), but it's still not working properly -- I think you may need a fundamentally different approach because your tree swaps x and y coordinates and that messes things up quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks. There is one issue of not able to move the node correctly. Another issue was that the link to be correctly connected to the node. I found that d.x, d.y values define the links end points, while the transform value decide the node end points. Here is a change I did http://jsfiddle.net/S4dyL/2/. Here I hard coded the position of the node and links, and now the two connects. When you click the dragged node, the expansion of it starts from the old position. How to update this in the tree ? Thanks again.

Comment: The main problem I see is that, as I've said, the coordinates are swapped to get the horizontal orientation of the tree and there's a lot of code around it. I would suggest starting with a minimal example here.

Comment: Thx. I got the drag and drop working now. The issue was that the links were following svg cordinate and nodes follow a different system, and hence for the transform operation I had to pass the delta between the old point and the new point. Here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/S4dyL/4/. Once thing I noticed is the labels dont get moved when we moved the item. Any idea how to make the label move as well ? Thanks again.

Comment: It might be easiest to group the node and label under a `g` element and move that on drag.